# LaTeX Error: Missing 'biblatex' package

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, overleaf

I'm working on my Overleaf document and I try to use the `natbib` Bibliography management and for my `.bib` document I always use Zotero, but when I try to compile I still getting this error

```
     LaTeX Error: Missing 'biblatex' package.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.16   {}
         
The bibliography requires the 'biblatex' package.
```

Here's some of my code and the `.bib` that I used.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\title{Lectura de Robert  S. Langer}
\author{Agustín Villarreal Carrillo}
\date{\today}

\makeatletter
\let\thetitle\@title
\let\theauthor\@author
\let\thedate\@date
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Tarea 1}
\lhead{\theauthor}
\rfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\input{Portada}
\input{MarcoTeorico}
\input{Conclusiones}

\bibliography{Sample}

\end{document}
```

The `.bib` docuement is

```
@misc{noauthor_professor_nodate,
    title = {Professor {Robert} {S}. {Langer} – {Langer} {Lab}},
    url = {https://langerlab.mit.edu/langer-bio/},
    language = {en-US},
    urldate = {2022-01-19},
    file = {Snapshot:C\:\\Users\\agust\\Zotero\\storage\\JNKZG75X\\langer-bio.html:text/html},
}

@misc{noauthor_robert_nodate,
    title = {Robert {Langer}: {El} ingeniero químico que ayudó a cambiar la medicina – {Fundación} {Centro} {Diagnóstico} {Nuclear}},
    shorttitle = {Robert {Langer}},
    url = {https://www.fcdn.org.ar/robert-langer-el-ingeniero-quimico-que-ayudo-a-cambiar-la-medicina/},
    language = {es},
    urldate = {2022-01-19},
    file = {Snapshot:C\:\\Users\\agust\\Zotero\\storage\\HBUT3GZD\\robert-lang
```

I appreciate any help that you can answer, thank you all!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I'm afraid it's not possible at the moment to fully replicate the issue you are experiencing since only you have access to the files `Portada.tex`, `MarcoTeorico.tex`, and `Conclusiones.tex`. You mention that you compile your LaTeX document on the Overleaf platform. Have you maybe inadvertently checked a box that says that the document's bibliography should be processed with `biber` instead of `bibtex`? You may want to contact Overleaf's help desk in this matter; I hear their LaTeX support staff is top-notch.

Comment: Off-topic: Instead of `title = {Professor {Robert} {S}. {Langer} – {Langer} {Lab}},`, you may want to write `title = {{Professor Robert S. Langer – Langer Lab}},`. Less code clutter, for sure.

Comment: Clear the cache as described in https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache. This error is usually caused by outdated auxiliary files.